# Help with understanding the following iterations of a Peano Curve

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, curves

I have recently read about the Peano Curve and I have found and understood the iteration using a square and the subdivisions of it into 9 other squares. So the process I understand is in the figure below:

[image]

I do not quite understand how it goes in this case however. I quite don`t understand how it gets from the first iteration to the second.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand it either, where did you get that from? There is no "obvious" recursion, and what's worse there is no obvious parameterization at each step (as there is in the first example), which is necessary in order to prove that the limiting object is actually a continuous curve, as required for the Peano curve.

Comment: You can find it everywhere on the internet when searching this curve, it appears even on wikipedia.

Comment: Perhaps you could augment your question, then, by editing it to add your investigations regarding more specific details said on the internet and/or wikipedia regarding the parameterization and recursion, and what you don't understand about those details.